# change class text value on a different webpage from a form jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a jQuery script that updates p .alertText with whatever the user submits in a form.  This script works fine on the same webpage, but I want it to change the value of p .alertText on a different webpage.  Example, the form is located on alert.html and when submitted I want it to change the p .alertText on index.html.

My next problem is that when p .alertText is updated, it does not save the new value.  Once the webpage is loaded it goes back to the default value of nothing.  Do I need to use a database to save this data, or can I just use a variable in the script?

Here is my jQuery script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var changeAlert = document.querySelector(".alertText");

 $("#subNow").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var res = $("form").serializeArray().map(function(input) {
       return input.value
   }).join(" ");
   changeAlert.innerHTML = res;

 });

 });
```

It is changing the < p class="alertText>

on a webpage.

Comment: Use a `database` or `localstorage` or `cookies` https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will need to use LocalStorage or Cookies. Check out this link for help with LocalStorage: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Its a bit old but it will help.